# Android: OnKeyListener camera button?

Tags: android

I'm currently making a game for Android in which I'd like to be able to shoot using the camera button (Or a different hardware button I don't mind, just tapping the screen would be rubbish).

In my view I have:

```
public class GameFrame extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnKeyListener{
    public GameFrame(Context context){
        ...
        setOnKeyListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            shoot();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This however doesn't do anything, shoot() is never called even when I'm furiously hitting all the keys on my phone!
Is there something obvious I've missed out, or have I done it completely wrong?

Cheers

Comment: maybe because your listener is applied to nothing?

Comment: Is it not attached to my view? I assumed that's what setOnKeyListener(this) did....

Comment: the keyListener has to be attached to a view. setOnKeyListener(this) -> this represents the fact your listener is implemented in your activity, not in a dedicated listener. You have to attach your listener to something, button, text input, and so on..

Comment: Ok thanks, what method does the attaching?
Say I have my GameFrame called m_gf, can I attach it to this? It extends View...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and the listener properly attached to your SurfaceView. The problem here is a little misunderstanding:

When you attach a `OnKeyListener` to a `View`, the listener *only* receives key events when the particular view is focused. This is neccessary to distinguish between key listeners in case multiple views exist in an activity. Most likely your view isn't focused on startup.

You can focus the view in code, which I **don't** recommend because the user might clear the focus by accident if you have other views too. Here is a small snippet how your code has to be changed, just for reference/understanding:

```
public class GameFrame extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnKeyListener{
    public GameFrame(Context context){
        ...
        setOnKeyListener(this);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```

The way **better alternative** is to get all key events in your activity, independent of which view is focused. This can be done by overriding the activities [`onKeyDown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) method. Add something like this to your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        shoot();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for example you have a layout with a button called btn. You declare this button in your onCreate method by doing :

```
//This 'called' your layout, you could access elements of your layout
setContentView('R.layouts.name_layout');
// You call the button you're interested in
Button btn = this.findViewById(R.your_button_in_layout);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

It is easier to understand with the onClick method, but it is the same thing with the OnKeyListener method.
Look at that : http://www.androiddevelopment.org/category/code-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeremy said, is your listener even being used? (I say this because you should get a response from key presses with that code). And if you want to use the camera button, make use of the [keycode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_CAMERA) for it. Good luck!